# How to fetch particular time frame using sql query when data is in epoch time format?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch data where the time range is between 7am to 12am, but the data is in epoch time format.
Please help me with this.

Database looks like this:

```
ID Timestamp
1  1591622630224
2  1591622632812
3  1591622635282
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Your Unix timestamp is measured in milliseconds rather than seconds.  So we need to take that into account.

Arithmetic is one method:

```
where mod(timestamp, 24*60*60*1000) >= 7 * 60*60*1000 and
      mod(timestamp, 24*60*60*1000) < 12 * 60*60*1000
```

Or convert to a time:

```
where time(from_unixtimestamp(timestamp / 1000)) >= '07:00:00' and
      time(from_unixtimestamp(timestamp / 1000)) < '12:00:00'
```

It turns out that these are subtly different.  The arithmetic method operates in UTC.  The `from_unixtimestamp()` method appears to take day list saving time into account.

Comment: It's working as expected. Please tell me what format to use if it was in seconds format, not milliseconds.

Comment: @Gokkul . . . You would remove all the `1000`s from the answer.